# Sorting multi-level Perl hash (dynamically based on arithmetic)

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, printing

How do I sort(and print) a multi-level perl hash based on key value ?

```
%hash = (
  a => { k1 => 51, k2 => 52, k3 => 53 },
  b => { k1 => 61, k2 => 62, k3 => 63 },
  c => { k1 => 71, k2 => 72, k3 => 73 },
)
```

For example sort the above hash numerically based on the value of `k2`?
So it should print:

```
52,62,72
```

I wanted to know how I can expand sorting single level hashes to multilevel using

```
sort { $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a} } keys %hash`
```

**Edit**

If I have another hash

```
my %property = ( a => 7, b => 6, c => 5 )
```

Can I sort `%hash` based on numerical value of  `$hash{key}{k2} * $property{key}` 
using

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
  a => { k1 => 51, k2 => 52, k3 => 53 },
  b => { k1 => 61, k2 => 62, k3 => 63 },
  c => { k1 => 71, k2 => 72, k3 => 73 },
);

my %property = ( a => 7, b => 6, c => 5 );


foreach (sort { ($hash{$a}{'k2'}*$property{$a}) <=> 
                ($hash{$b}{'k2'}*$property{$b}) } keys %hash)
{
    printf("[%d][%d][%d]\n",
    $hash{$_}{'k2'},$property{$_},$hash{$_}{'k2'}*$property{$_});
}
```

result should be

```
72,52,62    as products are (360(72*5),364(52*7),372(62*6))
```

Comment: Do you want to sort the `k2` values (`52, 62, 72`) alphabetically by the 1st level key (`a, b, c`), or do you want to sort all `k2` values  numerically?

Comment: [And what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Added an extra question

Comment: @Jean That is a completely new (although loosely related) question. As such, [ask a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program does as you ask. It first list the values of the `k2` elements sorted by their value, then the same elements sorted by their product with the corresponding element of the `%property` hash.

Note that your expected output of `52,72,62` is wrong. The products are, as you say, `a => 364, b => 372, c => 360` so the values should be sorted in the order `c, a, b` or `72, 52, 62`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
  a => { k1 => 51, k2 => 52, k3 => 53 },
  b => { k1 => 61, k2 => 62, k3 => 63 },
  c => { k1 => 71, k2 => 72, k3 => 73 },
);

my %property = ( a => 7, b => 6, c => 5 );

print join ',', map { $hash{$_}{k2} } sort {
  my ($aa, $bb) = map { $hash{$_}{k2} } $a, $b;
  $aa <=> $bb;
} keys %hash;
print "\n";

print join ',', map { $hash{$_}{k2} } sort {
  my ($aa, $bb) = map { $hash{$_}{k2} * $property{$_} } $a, $b;
  $aa <=> $bb;
} keys %hash;
print "\n";
```

**output**

```
52,62,72
72,52,62
```

Comment: `sort { $hash{$b}{k2}*$propery{$b} <=> $hash{$a}{k2}*$property{$a} } keys %hash` seems like working..Are there any pitfalls with this approach ?

Comment: @Jean: None except that it violates the [*DRY* (Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) development principle. If you manually duplicate anything then there is a chance that the duplicate won't agree with the original. Your comment is an excellent example!

Comment: It is not clear to me what is being duplicated here ? `$a/$b` ?

Comment: @Jean: The expression `$hash{$_}{k2}*$property{$_}`

Answer (score 3):

```
sort {$hash{$a}{'k2'} <=> $hash{$b}{'k2'}} keys %hash
```

The spaceship operator numerically compares the left-hand side with the right-hand side. It's most often seen in its simplest case, with

```
$a <=> $b
```

but in this case, you want to compare values from a hash and it can do that too.

Comment: I'd go with the special `->` operator: `sort $hash{$a}->{k2} <=> $hash{$b}->{k2} keys %hash;`. It's easier to read -- especially if the OP is going to add another hash to the hash.

Answer (score 3):

Get a list of all values in the hash:

```
values %hash;
```

transform a list of hashrefs to the contents of the `k2` entry:

```
map $_->{k2}, @list
```

oh, skip it if it's `undef`/doesn't exist:

```
map $_->{k2} // (), @list
```

sort a list numerically:

```
sort { $a <=> $b } @list
```

connect the dots:

```
sort { $a <=> $b } map { $_->{k2} // () } values %hash;
```

Comment: @mpapec Nah, you mentioned `join`, which I forgot. Our answers are complementary

Answer (score 2):

```
print join ",", sort { $a <=> $b } map { $_->{k2} } values %hash;
```

Answer (score -1):

Go with [ysth's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17196464/368630) answer, but this syntax may make things a bit easier to understand:

```
sort { $hash{$a}->{k2} <=> $hash{$b}->{k2} } keys %hash;
```

Remember that `$a` and `$b` are hash keys assigned randomly by the sort. You have no idea what key is being assigned to `$a` or what key is being assigned to `$b`. At one time `$a = "k1"` and another time `$b = "k1"`. You don't even know how many times the comparison is being done. All you know is that `$a` and `$b` are assigned to values of keys in your hash, and your job is to compare those two keys to get the results you want.

This isn't going to work:

```
sort { $hash{$a}->{k2} * $property{$a} <=> $hash{$b}->{k2} * $property{$b} } keys %hash;
```

because `$a` and `$b` will be assigned the values `k1`, `k2`, or `k3`. You don't have those keys in your `%property` hash. You'll probably get a bunch of warnings.

What do you do if your sorting algorithm is more complex than a simple one liner? You can specify a subroutine to do your sorting for you.

For example, instead of sorting on k2, you want to sort on the sum of all the values in your hash. That is `$hash{a}->{k1} + $hash{a}->{k2} + $hash->{k3}...` vs. `$hash{c}->{k1} + $hash{c}->{k2}...`, and I have no idea what any of the keys are. This subroutine will find all the keys in `%{ hash{$a} }` and add them up and compares them vs. all the keys in `%{ hash{$b}  }`:

```
sort sort_function keys %hash;

sub sort_function {

    # Sum of all the values in the hash %{ $hash{$a} }
    my $sum_a = 0;
    for my $hash_key ( keys %$hash{$a} ) {
       $sum_a += $hash{$a}->{$hash_key};
    }
    # Sum of all the values in the hash %{ $hash{$b} }
    my $sum_b = 0;
    for my $hash_key ( keys %$hash{$b} ) {
       $sum_b += $hash{$b}->{$hash_key};
    }
    return $sum_a <=> $sum_b;
}
```

Comment: `ysth` didn't post an answer. Do you mean `YatesCM`? If so then all you have done is add unnecessary `->` indirection operators, which I think is noisy and *less* clear. Also, you say the keys of `%hash` are `k1` .. `k3` when they are actually `a` .. `c`: the same as the keys of `%property`, so the sort statement you say won't work is absolutely fine.